# Make a conditional regex

Tags: php, regex

I am making an API and I want to implement an option to filter so I want to validate the expression with a regexp. this is the expression send in request.

```
filter[price] = gt.5 and lt.10
```

The rules: the first characters represent the operator to be used example:

```
gt = '>'
ge = '>='
lt = '<'
le = '<='
eq = '='
ne = '<>'
like = 'like'
ilike = 'ilike'
```

then there is a point to separate the value to be compared and optionally there would be other expression separated by the 'and' or 'or' operators.

This is the regex that I have built

```
$re = '/([a-z]{2,5}\.[\w0-9]+)(\s)*(?(2)(and|or)\2+([a-z]{2,5}\.[\w0-9]+))/i';
```

I want to make the regex take as valid the following cases and that I take as invalid any other case different from those

```
case 1: gt.5 (valid)
case 2: gt.5 and lt.10 (valid)
case 3: gt.5 and lt.10 or eq.5 (valid)
```

when I test the regex it works for both cases but it also matches for the following cases but these should be considered invalid.

```
case 4: gt.5lt.10 (should be invalid)
case 5: gt.5and (should be invalid)
case 6: gt.5..lt.10 (should be invalid)
```

Comment: The first thing you need to fix is the missing `/x` flag and readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might do instead of using an if clause is optionally repeat the second part with the `and` and `or` to match multiple parts, and use anchors to prevent partial matches.

**Note** that `\w` also matches a digit 0-9. In the example data, there are digits after the dot, so you could just use `\d` instead preventing to match `gt.5and`

```
 ^[a-z]{2,5}\.\d+(?:\h+(?:and|or)\h+[a-z]{2,5}\.\d+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/doGCAr/1)

You could make the this part `[a-z]{2,5}` more precise using an alteration listing all the options `(?:g[te]|l[te]eq|ne|i?like)`

---

A more specific variant could be using the alternation, and recurse the subpattern using `(?1)` to make it a bit more succinct.

```
^([gl][te]|eq|ne|i?like)\.\d+(?:\h+(?:and|or)\h+(?1)\.\d+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([gl][te]|eq|ne|i?like)` Match any of the alternatives
- `\.\d+` Match 1 `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\h+(?:and|or)\h+` Match either `and` or `or` between 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
  - `(?1)\.\d+` Recurse the first subpattern and match `.` and 1+ digits
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times to also allow a single `gt.5`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6TqHvU/1)

Comment: `[gl][te]` to reduce the first two branches